# Transfer drupal 7 content types

Tags: 7, migrations

I have a Drupal install with 10 content types and 30 views being used as web app. The app uses MySQL as a database.

What I would like to do is to reuse the same app but with SQLite. Is there a way to migrate the theme, content types and views without re-building them from scratch? I am not interested in the content.

Comment: What does "migrate the theme" mean? Drupal theme is just a set of files. It has nothing to do with database migration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export content types using features](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39417/export-content-types-using-features)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about migrating a database to a different database engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export all your config using [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module: This module dumps to code several config data as content types and Views (but no content), generating modules that once enabled in another site regenerate dumped config.

One you have your config exported install a new Drupal site over SQL Lite and enable the exported modules with the config.

To 'migrate' the theme you only have to copy the theme folder to the new installed site right folder (usually /sites/all/themes/ or /sites/all/themes/custom/).

Comment: sites/themes/all is wrong path :)

Comment: Oops, yes, you are right, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If all what you need is just moving your site to SQLite database you can use special converter scripts like [mysql2sqlite.sh](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776). Another way is using [DBTNG Migrator](https://www.drupal.org/project/dbtng_migrator) module.