# Best way to Improve live site and then push changes from dev to live?

Tags: 7, database

Currently I am applying a new Drupal theme on an existing site. 
I have created a separate instance for Development and copied the live site database and started working.

The new theme requires many new features ( modules, blocks, views etc ). I am just writing down every thing and of-course I need to redo it on live site once the theming is completed.

Is it possible that my Dev database gets updated automatically if changes are made on live site?

So once the theming is finished, I can drop the live DB and replace with Dev DB? Seems like a dream to me ..

Any help ?

Comment: no , i am using Drupal 7. i would like the Development database to auto update with the changes being made in the live site , and at the same time   i will keep working on development. Once i am done, i will replace live database with dev database.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but I think there is something misleading in your question: it appears that you are not just "re-theming" the site (= change the look and feel of it, by changes to a Drupal ***theme***), you're also working on "***many new features***" (maybe enable/disable contrib or custom modules, or creating/updatings views?). If my perception is right (is it?) then I'd avoid using the term "re theming", and simply call it something like "applying maintenance and/or improving the site".

Comment: yes you are right. I am implementing a new design with many new features.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible that my dev database gets updated automatically if changes are made on live site ?
>
> So once the theming is finished, i can drop the live DB and replace with Dev one:) Seems like a dream to me ..

Databases shouldn't be migrated up (ie dev -> prod), only down (ie prod -> dev). If you migrate a database up, you will overwrite anything new on the production server. For example, any new accounts, comments, pages, or anything else that is in the database.

If you use the Features module, it will allow you to migrate some database settings as code (a features module) that can potentially solve your issue. Or if you are on D8, you can export configuration and import it in the other site.

Comment: Thats why i am looking for some thing to sync my dev with live automatically.

Comment: Other than the features module, I don't know of anything that does this, which is why I mentioned that module.

Comment: But if this questions ends up in using features, then it has been answered already: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39417/export-content-types-using-features

Comment: No, i am still looking for DB Sync from Live to Dev ( one way )

Comment: As far as I know databases synchronisation does not exist on drupal, what does exist is [drush aliases](https://dev.acquia.com/blog/use-drush-to-sync-your-drupal-installations-between-multiple-environments/06/04/2016/10236) -which again imports data from one db to another, not sych- and [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).